# How to edit modified working directory files in pre-commit hook?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hook, commit

I've been doing mercurial hooks, and the standard hooks seem to work fine for most things.  But what I want to do is modify the files that are being committed, in a hook, before they are committed, but after the commit command is executed.  I've done the research:

pre-commit doesn't work because we do not have access to the changeset

commit doesn't work because any changes made are done so after the changeset is recorded, and will not be caught in this commit

pretxncommit doesn't work because you explicitly aren't allowed to modify the working directory

Regardless, I've tried those three, and also precommit (without the dash) which some have suggested is different from pre-commit - but it still suffers from the same limitation.  I need to know the list of files in the changeset, and be able to change them before they are sent to the commit.

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you need to modify the list of files being committed? To me it sounds like a bad idea as it means you won't commit what you are told to commit. Maybe rather make a hook which denies the commit, if your pre-conditions aren't met?

Comment: It's the obvious reason, I guess.  And you are going to say it's a bad idea.  I want to automatically format the code before the commit.  My coding style is different from my co-workers, but it's just minor stuff like brace positioning and whitespace.  Alternatively, it would work for me too if I could just format it before a push.

Comment: Install a pre-commit hook which denies badly-formatted code. And teach your editor to format the code as you need it.

Comment: Interesting use-case, I can imagine using it. I wonder if this would be possible with git.

Comment: Yes, git has `pre-receive` "Enforce project coding standards" http://githooks.com

Comment: My editor already can format the code but that's not acceptable from my standpoint, because then I have tell it to format it before commit, and then I have to tell it to unformat it after the commit, and I have to do that for every file every time.  As a programmer, the inefficiency in that would literally kill me.  I need a way to build that into mercurial.  I already wrote the python hooks even, I have it formatting one way after commit, and then formatting another way after update - but due to the issues I already mentioned, it doesn't work how I want it to.

Comment: @gsl: I'm not convinced that git's `pre-receive` hook actually does what you advertise it does; from the documentation it only allows to check the validity of the refs pushed, not to modify them. Thus it's the functional equivalent to mercurial's `pretxnchangegroup` hook.

Comment: @mironomi: The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that what you want is fundamentally opposing version control: you want it to store something else than what you check it. That's violating fundamental principles of version control. A VCS is the wrong place to modify files. It's an editor which does. There exists the EOL extension however. You could probably start a hack based on that which modifies more than just line endings, but I don't recommend to go that way. Maybe the keywords extension is even more in that direction

Comment: @planetmaker yes, you are right. It seems even `git` does not allow it.

Comment: @planetmaker:  You are right in that sense, it does violate VCS ideals...  However in my case it does so in a small enough way that I still feel it's legitimate.  So i would still prefer a commit hook.  That said, a workaround that would suffice for me would be a separate script that would do the formatting for me on the modified files.  In this case I would call the script manually prior to calling hg commit.  But in this case I still need the script to know which files are added and modified, etc, so that it can format the correct files.  One way to achieve this might be to have the script c

Comment: call hg status and then parse the output..  But i think this is still not ideal.

Comment: I think I've decided how I'm going to do this. I'm going to use precommit to call a script that parse hg status for modified and added files, then I'll have that script format for me.  Pretty hackish, but it does what I want.  Should I write this as an answer and accept it?